# Why isn't my home partition mounted automatically but mounting it manually in emergency mode works fine?

Tags: linux, boot, mount, login, fstab

If I boot my system (Arch), it puts me into emergency mode, and the home (LVM partition) isn't mounted. If I mount it manually with `mount /dev/Disks/Home /home`, the computer works normally then. My fstab seems fine; I don't see any errors in it.

Here is the screen when it happens. The Czech text with question marks is that I am supposed to give root's password. If I press Enter in this situation (with the command typed), the computer shows the graphical login screen and works fine.
[image]

It tells me to view system logs, so I looked at them, but I didn't see notice anything special, although the logs are very hard to read.

This is my fstab. I see nothing wrong there.

```
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# /dev/sdc2
UUID=fbd0fee1-0d24-4371-adf9-363d5cfbf7a2   /   ext4    rw,relatime 0 1

# /dev/sdc1
UUID=7E93-4801  /boot   vfat    rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2

# /dev/Disks/Home
/dev/Disks/Home /home   ext4    defaults    0 2

# swap file
/swapfile   none    swap    defaults    0 0
```

What is wrong with my system, or how would I diagnose what is wrong? The computer is supposed to boot directly into graphical login.